# Evaluate the following integral

Tags: integration

Calculate the integral $$\int^{\pi/2}_{0}{\ln(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x)}dx$$ 
I tried several methods but can't get any answer.

Comment: "I tried several methods" Excellent! Please show them.

Comment: I am on the correct path but stopped at the step dealing with the integral of log.

Comment: Well, we cannot say since you show nothing.

Answer (score 4):

By setting $x=\arctan t$ the problem boils down to evaluating
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log\left(a^2\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}+b^2\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)}{1+t^2}\,dt = -\pi\log 2+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(a^2 t^2+b^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt \tag{1}$$
and that is simple through differentiation under the integral sign. If
$$ f(c) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(t^2+c)}{1+t^2}\,dt \tag{2} $$
we have $f(0)=0$ and for every $c>0$
$$ f'(c) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{(t^2+c)(t^2+1)} = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{c+\sqrt{c}}\tag{3} $$
by partial fraction decomposition. It follows that:
$$ f(c) = \pi\log(1+\sqrt{c})\tag{4} $$
and the original integral equals:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta)\,d\theta=\color{red}{\pi\log\left(\frac{|a|+|b|}{2}\right)}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: Nice try but are you sure there's no error when substituting x=arctant?

Comment: I think there's a mistake at the beginning. If $x=\arctan x$ then $\sin x=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$

Comment: Yeah, exactly as I thought. Anyway, the method really solves this question. Thank you!

Comment: @TehRod: you are right, I am going to fix it.

Comment: @TehRod: now fixed. I do not mind the downvote, but for the next time (if happening) I would appreciate a mistake to be pointed out *before* downvoting. It is a pity to write down a working answer, that gets spoiled only by a silly computation mistake.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I didn't downvote, I'm usually very impressed with your answers

Comment: @TehRod: in that case, sorry, and thanks for your support anyway. My previous words are directed to the downvoter.